# Difficult in the language of banana

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, language

> I'm looking for a name.
>   Totally uncommon, yet strangely familiar.
>   Starts with ein affirmation, ends with a metal.
>   Middle is a vulgar intensifier.
>   Extremely difficult in the language of banana.

What is my name?

Hint:

> Banana is a loanword.

Comment: Is the "ein" correct?

Comment: This riddle is simply great +1 :)

Comment: @rhsquared It might be, or it might nicht be.

Comment: nicht... German, is it? ....hey, wait a minute... I might be on to something...

Comment: @user477343 That sounds about reich.

Comment: Okay, I think (ROT13) gur jbeq fgnegf jvgu "wn" orpnhfr gung nssvezngvba cneg ersref gb Trezna, nf "rva" zrnaf "ba" (nppbeqvat gb Tbbtyr Genafyngr). Naq onfvpnyyl, gur fvzcyrfg jbeq gb qrfpevor nssvezngvba vf rdhny gb nssvezngvir: "lrf". Va Trezna, gung vf "wn". $\ast$ However, I don't know the metal part. The vulgar intensifier part might refer to (ROT13) fbzr xvaq bs cuenfr/rkcerffvba vagrafvsvrq ol na npebalz be "grkg gnyx" nf gurl fnl. $\ast$ I am not too sure, though. I have a feeling that.. well.. (ROT13) Gur nafjre zvtug or LBHE anzr... $\ast$ I don't wanna look at the answer below...

Comment: ...yeah that would explain the strangely familiar part, but the banana part? I don't know.

Comment: @jafe, is the banana difficulty how you came up with your username, or did you discover it afterwards?

Comment: @El-Guest Came across it randomly googling my name :)

Comment: That's one nifty bit of trivia! (And my apologies for not noticing it was your name and not a username @jafe!)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The name is

> Jafe :D

Starts with ein affirmation, ends with a metal.

> Affirmation is "ja" (means "yes" in German), and Fe is a metal (iron)

Middle is a vulgar intensifier

> af ("as f***")

**Edit:**
I am intrigued by the last clue, but figuring anything out is difficult since

> we don't know *for sure* where the word "banana" came from - apparently it was originally an Arabic word, then integrated into a west-African language, and was finally introduced to us through Spanish and Portuguese :)

Comment: Too easy, huh? :P I wonder if anyone will figure out the monkey business on the last line.

Comment: (ROT13) "Nssr" zrnaf zbaxrl va trezna, znlor gung vf jung gur onanan ynathntr vf ersreevat gb?

Comment: Is it (rot13)whfg gurer gb znxr gur vavgvny yrggref fcryy bhg "Vg'f zr"?

Comment: @jafe (rot13)V fcrnx n yvggyr ovg bs Trezna so that gave it away :)

Comment: I think you're right about that edit; see my answer below and feel free to add it! Great job solving this, @Eutherpy!

Comment: And the initial letters of each line spell "its me", which is a rather huge hint.

Answer (score 16):

To finalize @Eutherpy's answer, I just wanted to solve the banana business:

> It is hypothesized that banana came from the Senagalese/West African language [Wolof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolof_language).

And in that language,

> Jafe means [difficult](https://www.livelingua.com/peace-corps/Wolof/Wolof%20Dictionary.pdf)!!

Answer (score 3):

I guess that Eutherpy posted just correct answer but I think it has another solution:

> Justin

Affirmation:

> Just

Metal:

> Tin

What about vulgar intensifier?

> **U**nresolved **S**exual **T**ension

Comment: Pretty good fit, although not exactly uncommon. What about the last line?

Comment: @jafe I don't know language of banana but I guess that lots of simple English words may be extremely difficult within. -OK I'm just justifying myself too much :)